# A lot of GarbageCollector calls before Firebase query start execution

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I found that Firebase performs slowly on some query even if it is on a small set of data.
I set Log Level to Logger.Level.DEBUG to see if i can find some information in the log cat.
Here, in the log cat, i found so many GarbageCollector calls befoe the firebase query started.

```
 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 119.246ms
 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 15.993ms
 I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 178740(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 6(1210KB) LOS objects, 20% free, 61MB/77MB, paused 20.261ms total 246.362ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 421369(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(30KB) LOS objects, 11% free, 63MB/71MB, paused 3.699ms total 150.208ms
 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 38.838ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 234760(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 11% free, 63MB/71MB, paused 3.761ms total 124.938ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 177455(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 8% free, 65MB/71MB, paused 4.031ms total 109.770ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 165051(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 65MB/71MB, paused 3.902ms total 105.397ms
 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 19.577ms
 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 30.319ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 133737(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 6% free, 66MB/71MB, paused 34.150ms total 116.078ms
 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 58.275ms
 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 31.344ms
 I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 239886(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 12(391KB) LOS objects, 19% free, 65MB/81MB, paused 4.279ms total 308.630ms
 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 19.896ms
 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 17.442ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 413361(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 67MB/75MB, paused 21.411ms total 169.188ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 230648(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 67MB/75MB, paused 4.088ms total 127.504ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 214282(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 9% free, 68MB/75MB, paused 3.783ms total 121.986ms
 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.059ms
 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.102ms
 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 25.963ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 160942(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 69MB/75MB, paused 33.338ms total 135.224ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 158679(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 69MB/75MB, paused 4.614ms total 119.459ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 149782(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 6% free, 70MB/75MB, paused 3.840ms total 100.132ms
 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 59.880ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 86107(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 9(221KB) LOS objects, 2% free, 73MB/75MB, paused 5.562ms total 66.501ms
 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 16.000ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 68706(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 8(204KB) LOS objects, 2% free, 73MB/75MB, paused 5.063ms total 68.463ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 66336(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 10(242KB) LOS objects, 1% free, 73MB/75MB, paused 5.038ms total 69.289ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 60331(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 7(177KB) LOS objects, 1% free, 74MB/75MB, paused 5.181ms total 54.786ms
 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 27.598ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 64552(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 7(155KB) LOS objects, 1% free, 74MB/75MB, paused 17.137ms total 81.332ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 48948(1803KB) AllocSpace objects, 7(158KB) LOS objects, 1% free, 74MB/75MB, paused 6.488ms total 63.935ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 46732(1694KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(59KB) LOS objects, 1% free, 74MB/75MB, paused 6.090ms total 62.455ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 39782(1456KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(46KB) LOS objects, 1% free, 74MB/75MB, paused 5.956ms total 63.859ms
 I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 339007(11MB) AllocSpace objects, 119(3MB) LOS objects, 18% free, 70MB/86MB, paused 4.144ms total 287.479ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 481371(17MB) AllocSpace objects, 83(2MB) LOS objects, 10% free, 71MB/79MB, paused 3.836ms total 136.776ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 306454(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 52(1234KB) LOS objects, 10% free, 70MB/78MB, paused 5.471ms total 103.283ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 186051(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 142(3MB) LOS objects, 10% free, 69MB/77MB, paused 4.630ms total 112.830ms
 I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 45.513ms for cause HeapTrim
 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 45.069ms
 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 214400(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 31(749KB) LOS objects, 7% free, 70MB/76MB, paused 3.877ms total 105.103ms
 D/Connection: conn_1 - Sending data: {d={a=q, r=2, b={h=bHJ1mWrKhIU9GTHaIkUYeaP43Bo=, p=/, ch={hs=[bALDIOju3KaZT2xWiQLaLKH0SBo=, qNZ6/TpSUd3ssEdVt8dTAg0tkyA=, qjHFAPcW191k7pdiKTTYKcoM4jA=, YuhYIGzgf5OgmLXVSuzPPXECeWc=, KuI8A5+9hRky9NolHYvkl7bilNU=, 55dGIfQzMgxtbAU/zpVoKfl3LuA=, 9VoUeg4sRIYfhTJugtwIANcdPH0=, b4/sKMEhxWFOqBH3uMbpiWAwH30=, s5xLa798i1518s9djUrjgyb18XE=, xw69BGenjYvwg7RILHBPtwXhVyQ=, aHCtTSD3ox+WXaryBp3uu3Nfz/g=, tC0zEvCLJljHSpbfgGWIZIcYdLo=, bcOAzAwkWR8yUVLYEdTpiNXxvxE=, rbaiPzhMDh7ahB1aSsJ8cf63MZg=, IUDU7S7GA0tL3UGjxmI45ofEX24=, NzdrheN8DXqBUfY+RM3L3q7hG4Q=, ekjUn4lnbwdGwje6+cNES2VKJxE=, fI1b1+/CRsQIMT3mt/i50nbQ8Y8=, E9mvQdFfiStRtZ8eJkBHhVAqnvo=, BOF1YmJJFg2Lusty1JgUnMEw3xI=, lbwxveJ9cFhXSfT2D0WOmWrmYMM=, clZotfKSAOhwccTaUYycSTgj15M=, xkoLdSPI8W+e+plppywrVOFFb5s=, INp7uMxgaFNCX4kkBx3GRNHsRAQ=, euVHoK0S/jbYsnD61W5Wje7W7cQ=, GAvJN0eMxpQ8qKVq8hF67Rf5dWo=, HVAHhdpBFbSocGKEVpZDHhW4Ub0=, +8UAZrKp2fa2LjCNvx3ZufTEz98=, P6npjI8doaqjVHRMmP+s4jpMnEw=, s63dTSOlc9KnJwkT919JwkZcEDc=, BTwTf/vfbWhrLurgoDfAKuPiBQc=, 2L2cggm9LZpebi96iAPnNZPvrrs=, 49jkc562TuijtnlzWffNZDcc37o=, anUpNiBJRBG/eRVS+0Ltx2I6xoI=, IpeSX9YxH1qFH31lCFcgFkcmlXg=, bsYBuq040IDqT819iN2hKksZigA=, hOMsvBVfgF7ZKjbhyXakfW58v+g=, P6xez6jyWnPfinDxJiqNgMleoY4=, lmR8RESBCH6Cbjx/eAvgtw1nGy4=, LDDo8VgDjES9bAfYf0JuKa4G3us=, 9WuZH2BjjTZX4FcEZI6Og2+wglY=, eigyHjZr3DrFM/MjVtJbtf9WWcM=, 3Ode5pkh9nlg0NY6RE1f+IwiccI=, F4xesQWVS+0V5+h/W5Xd3/mUh1E=, eSRLc9btLel7qW9sMdk6iq1YA8o=, DD5MeL9tChYUuFfK0fyLlcS13vo=, 9NvnQzTkuCEXa5rlDehkdyJ3QkI=, ISlqMDakB8yeehWI+w0sAHLDYL8=, d2nv4J6j9KeNJyf/23cMsFGnxp0=, JQu5Sf3mwF/gdFxntP1sX6go+Wc=, jdZ7Ng/wSQDJC85dOMb6kHJaZVA=, OyRG9SYCDDEGfwmYYK7EnwBVfD0=, mV1cnouAhXHAg1gFL+oM6vDk0K4=, 2G7PhMcrabq8bm8ucu1rc++jyfo=, 04r7kkwUEMCwxLl82W5lEZUFzwQ=, kxZiCIsxmYNmsn+5S3hXqKAQ1B0=, kjqNcnc87Roxx4jK5w9IfajXv18=, 5W5ltmvmCH2uJ7UzrPOMGlWhdNg=, 6BVCbfSQvEyliNsbJLksH1phDlA=, eYWv+u8Yp4vT6REToDi3ZFkCnkU=, b6b5kBTfHWT0Jv3fbn/DtHe1Two=, cR0wggN5fhYFJApgFKZMAFu9FYY=, obFhp1LRsmeYXnw6q39tcEbvIZk=, vD1zXBhHBT0u+KaR7dtPsNltkis=, /J1hZE92X92aC0GlECnsm+hF4tc=, fIDgCue4+UBUAiakpq8DrKKlb+o=, L5s5EOOBawNXDq1Qzne8+FCkP4M=, v8EVZoo16NlGwOjAwynL43pwa0Y=, OVfiRxAfMGtuLTi7WKEWN19vJ8E=, Fu+dPgUjDVDHW4CD9hBG6EjbsH4=, /hHBwp3jn88eHqWt2DtMDS2H8KQ=, NsIvujNzn18uwRkN06vhYcjTaSc=, dfASQGt5Qm3CQlIDcp1OeGRF6s4=, Sp/G1d3RFAKgMSR+//Uf+nR+Fug=, Vt3llCH3A/NECmtcbqAHVRnnXhk=, O56WoHNNa1rUEFzua7lbH5y4anA=, k1eZSSHDNS5aN9zsJ4vlE0je7cY=, 6Mn9ZqFp8hBSfZkfjEiR1dQ0oVU=, ctpxP/HfuNIGka2pVbvQee2k2eo=, h+jHwJ6Ppvb72+rmywuf4EK8gH4=, 512xoVjuUH7Rly+in9iQdlrU7nk=, vp57AKFRErjrDWG2NCGtbNlQIR8=, mqbYrJleKYpEdvT9ZDM5aUi2l/k=, vufp8Y6EXDKo/rJO0aVOL40WAWM=, 5gcElGrxGZJK7yiHEouhcz+QXh4=, JKoArtNvTCr0ET4yQhhPhuDJuqU=, 81stTPQmj0f5GkxCPrOLrOZIy7Y=, 1YluFfPncdYV1B+3Nyqksw22biI=, /T+je45nNFrVLLdD2okxP287D5U=, 26cmyM8dltqPRkeyd9kZay2z59I=, mHYxlmUbe1cwYsB9a87gxHRNb+U=, V1VGKgVsAsvBLG4kIGJ0ToMPXwk=, jhhxkLPVeJTSn9xVFEeOpwnn5+c=, I4hXdr/rhxm3rrwT8gec7+Gb+O8=, B/ke+zpb7n7zqm331PnZpzcINM0=, P1wbPYVaQK41TRLkvkYmVajrqkA=, 3pq/9cS67apkoGLJs09WDu3O6Ik=, y+TcFLKef1qyRAaexBfGfdl4awI=, qsZz8e8JKqKCfTACpmORWbKFWAU=, oIJS8GuJttgoOzTLOaLm0OeSQ0I=, p+bmPWYcjilFwxrbSL/l/qxhH2c=, ln3JW5ne3QxvyzCYRnzj+GaUnNg=, lFBj9a300XyDAK4WYA9xHGX1DSc=, pYdnAY/t9HjyXA9mCgNL9kKUAls=, lglAuBlXwGCDSM/xwq7mSnonoeM=, vyYQPIZb7ae828neRvMedglkQXM=, HHRnuDQuSnJIkOzgDbOw1pXwikk=, 1/TaNEsxa9eSK/l9Hd2vo0eUUuc=, zEsK0X3hzYRU7tCtAui7p20SgNQ=, Kxz1KBPUFjm73FDuaIxqHYUWcrQ=, M4T3sLsKhIjBF2n5rqcRQ3Gezy4=, ehE/3obD0woLxhxFRZImXRbLl14=, 5t5l2oAHI0se/BuavanDU8Xy+eo=, /ma9Aa7lwwmgPRIpZnK+L7r4Kkk=, VftPH6GBC+kNJ0mvgpB4KL07fv0=, Pq08isedk230HSbHIcuvtMi5aHI=, ++pnsz+wbybdUnZpaol44bhYds4=, mtRz1v6J7SbZQAI2z703JELlG74=, Q9bJeDtpf/B4O4NB2Uo5FDKmysc=, AfMe4uVvrK2cFHIdx2N/LcKwC+4=, EKaXGSUB2GGYIThPKFt3AKvZ3rU=, jqjJfCkF9aLo7eAyc8UJ2u4uOsA=, +hft27daYSvuWZ8dsgwhC7+VQj4=, dwjaXCITJqIZH1LwPplb7LNq8Ho=, Pbz4g+DcxprOt2ef8aUCNRyzfFE=, UB9ILOgzQZ+fA3G6I2Rcj9HyVmU=, ht3jvak0cAeSkuX9c7+LNzPCopk=, 7bEDyPX/QjUJFnkdoQ2Qubq8ang=, RHn75CDN80Jz3UQIVXGQPyIrgbg=, BXay0TBI3PlUH+bSsbd0UtvBd8I=, W8PxyIuVGta61mBe5JzdqLS7+Zg=, HzHQx4oxAirWHzbx5Atg3YsgdvU=, Swu1s+1wuaIPJTG67S
```

It causes a relatively long delay ( > 10 seconds ).
I set the persistence enabled to true and the Firebase verson i use is 9.4.0

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: I am currently having this same issue and made a very similar post. Will keep an eye on this for additional updates.

Comment: Hi @Ignacious. See the accepted answer below. It solved the issue.

Comment: Hey @DNY, yeah I do not have that piece of code anywhere, but I do not call persistence? should i do that?

Comment: Figured my issue out, was using .getinstance() for database reference and it was pulling a weird link and my ENTIRE DB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the log output you have provided (thank you!) it looks like you are actually listening to your entire Firebase Database (the "p=/" in the last line means you're starting a listen on /).  This is going to read the entire contents of your offline cache and do some processing on it so that we can send hashes of your cached data to the server to try to minimize the bandwidth incurred.  This is very likely to trigger a fair amount of GC activity, based on the size of the data.

Comment: Thank's Michael for pointing me in the right direction. There was a line in my Application onCreate where i called keepSynced(true) on the root reference of my firebase database. It was for testing purpose and i forgot to delete that method call. I deleted that line and everything works like a charm.